# Products Don't Show In New Categories When Using WooCommerce REST API To Update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

So the problem I'm having here isn't that I'm unable to set the new categories with the REST API.  I can POST and PUT to the product endpoint and set it to a new product category, but when I do the product does not show in the new category until I use the built in web editor to "Update" the product.  I know that my JSON is good because I get the response back indicating the product is now under the new category rather than the old one and when I go to the WP Admin product editor, the product now shows itself under that category in the checkbox selection tree.  But when going to that category on the site, it isn't there.  I also noticed that the category product counts don't update until I manually update the product in the WP Admin editor.  If this is the first product in that category then that category also isn't visible on the site because the product count still shows as 0.  I don't change any information in the WP Admin editor, just hit the Update button.

The way I'm seeing it, there must be a hook or function that is normally triggered to "Regenerate" the product when it is updated that is not occurring when it is updated with the REST API.  Does anybody have any clue how I can figure out what it is that isn't being triggered here?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar ongoing issue, after updating categories via api, menus constructed on those categories were empty.

In our case this might have something to do with polylang as well, as pushing different language categories ended up fixing the menu for the last language updated, but breaking for other languages.

Didn't find a proper fix, ended up adding a custom endpoint to call after api update for clearing taxonomy caches.

```
function my_custom_clear_cache() {
     if (function_exists('clean_taxonomy_cache')) {
           clean_taxonomy_cache('product_cat');
     }
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wc/v3', 'my_custom_clear_cache', array(
        'methods' => array('GET'),
        'callback' => 'my_custom_clear_cache',
    ));
});
```

`product_cat` is the taxonomy code for categories

After updating categories via api, call `GET /wp-json/wc/v3/my_custom_clear_cache`